# asp validation summary does not display even though validation fires up for requiredfieldvalidator

Tags: asp.net

The Validation Summary which is to be displayed:

```
<asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" DisplayMode="BulletList"  
 EnableClientScript="true" runat="server" ValidationGroup="downloadGrp" />
```

The required field validator:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel4" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional"> 
<ContentTemplate> 

    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" 
     ControlToValidate="txtReasonForDownload" 
     ValidationExpression="^[\s\S]{0,500}$" 
     ValidationGroup="downloadGrp" 
     ErrorMessage="Max. 500 characters allowed!" runat="server">
    </asp:RegularExpressionValidator><br /> 

    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" 
    ControlToValidate="txtReasonForDownload" EnableClientScript="false" 
    ErrorMessage="Reason is required!" ValidationGroup="downloadGrp" 
    SetFocusOnError="true" Text="*"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator> 

    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" CssClass="error" 
    Text="Reason for Download:"></asp:Label> 
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine"
       ValidationGroup="downloadGrp" 
       Width="200px" MaxLength="500" Enabled="False"></asp:TextBox><br /> 

</ContentTemplate>
```

The code behind:

```
protected void btnSubmitDownload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    string str1 = txtReasonForDownload.Text; 
    if (str1.Equals(string.Empty)) 
    { 
         reqTxtReason.IsValid = false; 
     //Response.Write("<script> alert('Reason for Download is required!'); </script>");

     } else { } 
 }
```

Although the requiredfieldvalidator is fired up, the validation summary does not display the validation.

Comment: move your validation summary/controls/button under same Updatepanel

Comment: But I want the validation summary on the top of the page, it works if I have it under the same update panel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed it by enclosing validation summary in another update panel and by using the same trigger as the other update panel